# Creating/re-factoring sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, refactoring

Currently, I have a table `items`, which contains an `id` column. I also have a `stores` table, which also contains just an `id` column. Lastly, I have a junction table `store_items`, which contains`item_id`, and `store_id` foreign keys. This table joins items to the stores that they're available at.

I need a way to get: either an item by id, or if the itemId variable is null, to get all items that are available at a store, and if the storeId variable is null, to get all items.

Currently, I have this, which is a total mess:

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.id 
FROM items AS i JOIN store_items AS si ON ITEMVAR IS NULL 
     AND (
         (STOREVAR IS NULL OR si.store_id = STOREVAR) 
          AND i.id = si.item_id
         ) 
     OR i.id = ITEMVAR;
```

Is it better practice to just separate the different queries, or is there a way to re-factor this?

Comment: Separate the queries. Mashing them into one obscures the intent, and adds nothing.

Comment: By the way, what's the desired behavior if the query has both `item_id` and `store_id`, but that item is not available at that store?

Comment: @Dmitri Ideally, to return an empty array to make it simple to check if an item exists at a store

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to use `EXISTS`, if you want it all in one query:

```
SELECT i.id
FROM items i
WHERE i.id = ITEMVAR or
      (ITEMVAR IS NULL AND
       EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM store_items si WHERE si.store_id = STOREVAR)
      ) or
      STOREVAR IS NULL;
```